# ng-pdfviewer downloads pdf instead of displaying pdf in ionic application

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, pdf, ionic-framework

I am trying to integrate an embedded `pdf` file in my ionic project so that users can read `pdf` files right within the application, but after implementing `ng-pdfviewer` the `pdf` file does not display on the android phone and it downloads instead of displaying when i try to view application on a web browser simulator like mozilla firefox bellow is a snippet of my controller and view page

```js
.controller('BookController',[ '$scope', 'PDFViewerService', function($scope, pdf) {
  console.log('TestController: new instance');

  $scope.pdfURL = "pdf/Maths_High_School_Science_Texts.pdf";

  $scope.instance = pdf.Instance("viewer");

  $scope.nextPage = function() {
    $scope.instance.nextPage();
  };

  $scope.prevPage = function() {
    $scope.instance.prevPage();
  };

  $scope.gotoPage = function(page) {
    $scope.instance.gotoPage(page);
  };

  $scope.pageLoaded = function(curPage, totalPages) {
    $scope.currentPage = curPage;
    $scope.totalPages = totalPages;
  };

  $scope.loadProgress = function(loaded, total, state) {
    console.log('loaded =', loaded, 'total =', total, 'state =', state);
  };
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-view view-title="{{pdfName}}">
  <ion-content class="padding">

<div class="" ng-controller="BookController">
  <h3>{{pdfName}}</h3>
  <!-- <div class="card"> -->

<!--   <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'pdf/1.html'"></div>

</div> -->
<div ng-controller="BookController" class="text-center container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn" ng-click="pdfURL='test.pdf'">Load test.pdf</button>
          <button class="btn" ng-click="pdfURL='test2.pdf'">Load test2.pdf</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn" ng-click="gotoPage(1)">|&lt;</button>
          <button class="btn" ng-click="prevPage()">&lt;</button>
          <button class="btn" ng-click="nextPage()">&gt;</button>
          <button class="btn" ng-click="gotoPage(totalPages)">&gt;|</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="label" ng-show="totalPages">{{currentPage}}/{{totalPages}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <pdfviewer src="{{pdfURL}}" on-page-load='pageLoaded(page,total)' id="viewer" load-progress='loadProgress(loaded, total, state)'></pdfviewer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

After combing the internet for answers and contacting Andreas Krennmair the developer behind ng-pdfviewer i realized that the problem was with a plugin integrated with mozilla browser, it intercept the pdf file and downloads it before ionic is able to render it , so i dis-able IDM download manager plugin for mozilla firefox and it worked out fine, ---just like magic:)